# How can I expand Bluestacks memory in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory, sd-card, bluestacks

My computer recently updated to Windows 10.

Since then, Bluestacks (which I use mainly to access Whatsapp) has a very limited amount of space, and when I try to download pictures/videos it tells me that there isn't enough space on my SD card.

I tried following [these instructions](https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/bluestacks-sd-card-internal-memory-ram.html), which worked on my previous version of Windows. But while I successfully created a new SD card file and updated the registry "path" to point to it, it still seems to be accessing the old SD card. When I check the settings in Bluestacks, it still lists the SD card size as 2 GB even though the .fs file I pointed it to is much larger.

Are the settings different for the newer version of Windows / BlueStacks? How can I point Bluestacks to the new larger SD card file?

Comment: What's app has native windows support now

Comment: @stuck - only mirrors what's on your phone. I use bluestacks to access whatsapp without having it on a phone